# Getting a connect timed out error when using HttpRedis and eval modules for NGiNX

Tags: nginx, redis

I am trying to catch the value from Redis. So that I can echo it via a variable. This is why I am using eval block. But for some reason I am getting errors.

I don't get any config errors when I reload them.

Here are the errors I get after I try to load the page (nginx error.log):

```
2198 2013/05/15 19:46:00 [info] 18255#0: *22 client timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading client request line, client: [...]  server: [...]
2199 2013/05/15 19:46:00 [info] 18255#0: *23 client timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading client request line, client: [...], server: [...]
2200 2013/05/15 19:47:40 [info] 18345#0: *28 client timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading client request line, client: [...], server: [...]
```

My config:

```
location = /session {
            eval $session {
                    set $laravel "laravel:";
                    set $redis_key $laravel$cookie_session;
                    redis_pass [...]:6379;
                    error_page      404 502 504 = @fallback;
            }

            echo $cookie_session;
            echo ' - ';
            echo $session;
    }

    location @fallback {
            echo 'Error!';
    }
```

This is what I get in Google Chrome:

```
No data received
Unable to load the webpage because the server sent no data.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem had to do with the version I was using of the NGiNX-Eval-Module.

I downloaded the version presented in the documentation. They are a more recent version in the GitHub account.

Also I had to comment out some of the code in the ngx_http_eval_module.c file: 640:39 (just *pclcf), 631:32 (just *ecf), 675, and 675.

For more information: https://github.com/vkholodkov/nginx-eval-module/issues/10